# Auto generate controls with data from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, controls

I have data copies from datagridview1 to datagridview2 the data in datagridview2 I'm trying to figure out how to take specific columns and copy there contents over to another panel where that data will be put into labels, textboxs, comboboxes.  I first did it with another datagrid but its far to crowded to hold all the controls along with the data.  Below is and example picture of what I'm trying to recreate from a webpage we used to use but on a winform they now want to use, this shows 1 product however if datagridview2 has multiple entries then this would show multiple lines..etc

I have no idea how to go about this or if its even doable.

I'm thinking maybe the form generates a table layout view control with all the columns, adds rows depending on amount of rows from datagridview2 and generates the controls needed in each row for each cell from datagridview2.  I may be entirely wrong there, but I'm reaching the end of my knowledge on doing something like this, so here I am to be schooled =)

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Data can be edited in a DGV, why not that?  Consider what you are trying to do: you have one DGV with some data;  you **copied** some rows from it to another DGV; now you want to make **another copy**?  A pair of DataViews would eliminate all that.

Comment: DG1 is all the stock.  DG2 is the cart.  And DG3 is what you see in the picture.  That's just the way the powers that be want it.  I tried to create something in DG like what you see in the picture, and it looks horrible even full screen.  Everything is really squished.  But I don't know how to add Text Boxe's, Button and ComboBox to existing columns.

Comment: Errr, I wasnt talking about the number of DGVs, but the fact that for each one you are making fresh copies of the *data* for each.  Each DGV can present its own view of the same data.

Comment: Does DGV have a listbox column, I'm not seeing one but wanted to check.

Comment: *Why* cant you use the awesome edit capabilities of the DGV and edit them there?  There isnt a listbox, but there is a combobox.  Why do you need a set of controls for each row - the user can only edit one at a time.  You could a) make the DGV readonly and use it as a selector to display the selected row in various controls for edits b) create a usercontrol and spam them in a TLP